# Javascript Page Wipe Transition with Superscrollorama

Tags: javascript, transition

What I am trying to do is have different parts of a page slide up and cover up the previous part. I found what I wanted to do at http://johnpolacek.github.com/superscrollorama/, specifically the "Wipe It" portion. I tried copying some of the code and including the same javascript files.

In Firefox, it works. However, in Chrome and IE, when I try to scroll down, the scrollbar jitters and snaps back to the top of the page.

I don't have it up on a site, but I do have the files that I'm using: http://www.mediafire.com/?h28etrbr5t24qyw

Any help (or more practical alternatives) would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yea that looks pretty cool. I would just create the code from scratch so you can get it exactly how you want. I just created something real basic. A blue main div with a red div that wipes down. Obviously you can put whatever you want on both divs.. Heres the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type='text/css'>
      body{
        margin: 0px;
      }
      #wipeScreen{
        position: fixed;  
        width: 100%;                  
        background-color: red;
      }

      #mainScreen{
        position: absolute;
        background-color: blue;
        height: 200%;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      var visHeight;
      function loadConstants(){
        visHeight = Math.ceil(document.getElementById("mainScreen").offsetHeight/2);
        var wipeScreen = document.getElementById("wipeScreen");
        wipeScreen.style.height = visHeight+"px";
        wipeScreen.style.top = -visHeight+"px";
        window.onscroll = runScroller;
      }
      function runScroller(){
        document.getElementById("wipeScreen").style.top = pageYOffset-visHeight+"px";
      }    
    </script>        
  </head>
  <body onload='loadConstants()'>
    <div id='mainScreen'></div>
    <div id='wipeScreen'></div>  
  </body>
</html>
```

Copy and paste it into an HTML document and you will see what I mean

Comment: Looks great! However, it's still not working in Google Chrome (version 20, last time I checked). Strangely enough, it works on IE9, but of course not IE7 or IE8...

Comment: yea i just checked it on firefox and then IE9 but lemme see whats going on with chrome

Comment: Alright I updated the code, will work with chrome now, I calculated the height and offset after load so it doesn't have any breaks. Don't know much about Chromes style rendering engine but this works now. Yea IE is a nightmare to say the least, especially older versions